# Curry a function that takes abstract arguments in CPP

Tags: c++, functional-programming, abstract-class, currying

I would like to curry a function that takes an abstract argument. This makes my compiler angry:

```
#include <functional>

class MyAbstractParentClass {
public:
    virtual void someVirtualMethod() = 0;
};

class MyConcreteChildClass: public MyAbstractParentClass {
public:
    virtual void someVirtualMethod() override {}
};

void myFunction(const MyAbstractParentClass& myAbstractObject) {}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    const MyAbstractParentClass& myChildObject = MyConcreteChildClass();
    
    myFunction(myChildObject); // all good here
    
    const auto myCurriedFunction = std::bind(myFunction, myChildObject); // error here
    
    myCurriedFunction(); // we never get here
}
```

Is there a way I can make this work without resorting to pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` copies its argument, you might use reference with `std::reference_wrapper`

```
const auto myCurriedFunction = std::bind(myFunction, std::ref(myChildObject));
```

or use lambda:

```
const auto myCurriedFunction = [&](){ return myFunction(myChildObject); };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to curry a function, you can use `boost::hana::curry`, as shown below:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/curry.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int f(int x,int y,int z) {
    return x + y + z;
};

int main {
    auto constexpr f_curried = boost::hana::curry<3>(f);
    auto constexpr f12 = f_curried(1)(2);
    std::cout << f12(3) << '\n';
}
```

However, in your case you seem to be "partially" applying the function, rather than currying it. I use quotes because you're actually passing to it all the arguments it needs, and you're just delaying the call. To accomplish this, you can use `boost::hana::partial` from the `<boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>` header (but you still have to wrap the object in a reference, as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66228865/5825294) which actually tells you what's wrong in your original code):

```cpp
    using boost::hana::partial;
    const auto myCurriedFunction = partial(myFunction, std::ref(myChildObject));
```